# Object building on submit causes application to clog

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Overview**

I developed an employment application that has several different features. Long story short, there are a few sections within the application that allow you to add employment history, add address history, accident and license history, etc. At the end of the whole shebang, I build a JSON object and prepare it for submission to the server. That's the gist.

**The Problem**

Let's say you have a ton of job history over the last ten years, and you obviously will put almost all of it that you can remember, or that is relevant on the application. Let's say it's 12 jobs. Let's say you also have 3 total addresses in your address history. This will give us a total of 13 clone objects. Now the loop that I generated will read these just fine, but what happens is, and I'm guessing it's my loop structure, is that when the count on the cloned objects gets so high, it starts to cause a timeout error while looping and basically freezes.

**The Fix**

I need to find the error in my loop that may or may not be causing this.

I'll post my code below and a link to the live application so anyone who wants to take a shot at this can play around with it and see what I mean. It's taken a couple days of some incredible debugging to even get this far with it.

**Resources**

```
 $('#applicationForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from the default submission
    $('body').spin('large');
    var application_info = new Object(); //start the application form Object
    $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    if(checkHeadings(sections)){
        for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
            application_info[sections[i]] = new Object(); //create a new object for each section
            //traverse each select by form control 
            $("#"+sections[i]).find(".form-control").map(function (index, element){
                $(element).each(function (index){
                    var name = $(element).attr('name');
                    if((sections[i] !== 'addressRecords') && (sections[i] !== 'employmentHistory') && (sections[i] !== 'drivingExperience')){
                        application_info[sections[i]][$(element).attr('name')] = $('[name="'+name+'"]').eq(index).val(); //application_info 
                    }else if(sections[i] === 'addressRecords'){
                        application_info['addresses'] = $('.form-control').map(function (index, element) {
                            return {
                                line1: $('[name="address"]').eq(index).val(),
                                line2: $('[name="address2"]').eq(index).val(),
                                city: $('[name="city"]').eq(index).val(),
                                state: $('[name="state"]').eq(index).val(),
                                zip: $('[name="zip"]').eq(index).val(),
                                from_date: $('[name="from_date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                to_date: $('[name="to_date"]').eq(index).val()
                            };
                        }).get();
                    }else if(sections[i] === 'employmentHistory'){
                        application_info['employmentHistory'] = $('.form-control').map(function (index, element) {
                            return {
                                from_date: $('[name="emp_from_date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                to_date: $('[name="emp_to_date"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                company: $('[name="company"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                contact: $('[name="supervisor"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                phone: $('[name="company_phone"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                address: $('[name="company_address"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                city: $('[name="company_city"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                state: $('[name="company_state"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                zip: $('[name="company_zip"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                position_held: $('[name="position"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                reason_left: $('[name="reason_left"]').eq(index).val(), 
                                fmscr: $('.fmscr:checked').eq(index).val(), 
                                drug_testing: $('.drug_testing:checked').eq(index).val()
                            };
                        }).get();
                    }else if(sections[i] === 'drivingExperience'){
                        application_info['drivingExperience'] = {                            
                                tt_from_date : $('[name="tt-from-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                tt_to_date : $('[name="tt-to-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                tt_miles : $('[name="tt-miles"]').eq(index).val(),
                                st_from_date : $('[name="st-from-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                st_to_date : $('[name="st-to-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                st_miles : $('[name="st-miles"]').eq(index).val(),
                                accident_records : $('.form-control').map(function (index, element) {
                                    return {
                                        date : $('[name="accident-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        nature : $('[name="nature"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        location : $('[name="location"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        fatalities : $('[name="fatalities"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        injuries : $('[name="injuries"]').eq(index).val()
                                    };
                                }).get(),
                                traffic_citations : $('.form-control').map(function (index, element) {
                                    return {
                                        location : $('[name="citation-location"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        date : $('[name="citation-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        charge : $('[name="charge"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        penalty : $('[name="penalty"]').eq(index).val()
                                    };
                                }).get(),
                                license_records : $('.form-control').map(function (index, element) {
                                    return {
                                        state : $('[name="license_state"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        license_no : $('[name="license_no"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        type : $('[name="license_type"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        endorsements : $('[name="endorsements"]').eq(index).val(),
                                        date : $('[name="license_date"]').eq(index).val()
                                    };
                                }).get(),
                                qa : $('[name="qa"]:checked').eq(index).val(),
                                qa_explain : $('[name="qa_explain"]').eq(index).val(),
                                qb : $('[name="qb"]:checked').eq(index).val(),
                                qb_explain : $('[name="qb_explain"]').eq(index).val(),
                                qc : $('[name="qc"]:checked').eq(index).val(),
                                qc_explain : $('[name="qc_explain"]').prop('checked') ? 1 : -1,
                                qd : $('[name="qd"]:checked').eq(index).val()
                        };
                    }
                });
            }).get();
            if($('input[name="other"]').is(":visible")){
                application_info['generalInformation']['other'] = $('input[name="other"]').val();
            }else{
                application_info['generalInformation']['other'] = "";
            }
            application_info['selfIdentification'] = new Object();
            application_info['selfIdentification']['race'] = $('[name="race"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="race"]:checked').val() : "";
            application_info['selfIdentification']['gender'] = $('[name="gender"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="gender"]:checked').val() : "";
            application_info['selfIdentification']['disability'] = $('[name="disability"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="disability"]:checked').val() : "";
            application_info['selfIdentification']['veteran'] = $('[name="veteran"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="veteran"]:checked').val() : "";
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '../assets/server/application_process.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : application_info,
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function (data){
                $('body').spin(false);
                if(!data.errors){
                    $('#applicationForm').html("<h3>"+data.message+"</h3>");                                  
                }else{
                    bootbox.alert(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('body').spin(false);
        $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

The application:

http://www.driveforeagle.com/apply/page2

Comment: Wow..There's a lot here. Can you isolate the issue at all?

Comment: @MarkC. This is about as far as to issolation that we have. It's something to do with how to the sturcture of the loop, when building the object, is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part it seems like you have extra iteration.

```
$("#"+sections[i]).find(".form-control").map(function (index, element){
      $(element).each(function (index){
      ...
  })
})
```

You don't need `$(element).each(function (index){...}` - you are already iterating the selects in `map`.

EDIT

I tried to refactor your code as I understood your logic, expand below. There is still room for optimization but I hope that helps.

```js
$('#applicationForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from the default submission
    $('body').spin('large');
    var application_info = { //start the application form Object
        generalInformation: {
            other: $('input[name="other"]').is(":visible") ? $('input[name="other"]').val() : ""
        },
        selfIdentification: {
            race: $('[name="race"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="race"]:checked').val() : "",
            gender: $('[name="gender"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="gender"]:checked').val() : "",
            disability: $('[name="disability"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="disability"]:checked').val() : "",
            veteran: $('[name="veteran"]').is(":checked") ? $('[name="veteran"]:checked').val() : ""
        }
    };


    $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    if (checkHeadings(sections)) {
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            var sectionId = sections[i],
                $section = $("#" + sectionId);

            //traverse each select by form control 
            switch (sectionId) {
                case 'addressRecords':
                    obj['addresses'] = [];
                    $section.find('[name="address"]').each(function(index, element) {
                        obj['addresses'].push({
                            line1: $section.find('[name="address"]').eq(index).val(),
                            line2: $section.find('[name="address2"]').eq(index).val(),
                            city: $section.find('[name="city"]').eq(index).val(),
                            state: $section.find('[name="state"]').eq(index).val(),
                            zip: $section.find('[name="zip"]').eq(index).val(),
                            from_date: $section.find('[name="from_date"]').eq(index).val(),
                            to_date: $section.find('[name="to_date"]').eq(index).val()
                        });
                    });
                    break;

                case 'employmentHistory':
                    obj['employmentHistory'] = [];
                    $section.find('[name="address"]').each(function(index, element) {
                        obj['employmentHistory'].push({
                            from_date: $section.find('[name="emp_from_date"]').eq(index).val(),
                            to_date: $section.find('[name="emp_to_date"]').eq(index).val(),
                            company: $section.find('[name="company"]').eq(index).val(),
                            contact: $section.find('[name="supervisor"]').eq(index).val(),
                            phone: $section.find('[name="company_phone"]').eq(index).val(),
                            address: $section.find('[name="company_address"]').eq(index).val(),
                            city: $section.find('[name="company_city"]').eq(index).val(),
                            state: $section.find('[name="company_state"]').eq(index).val(),
                            zip: $section.find('[name="company_zip"]').eq(index).val(),
                            position_held: $section.find('[name="position"]').eq(index).val(),
                            reason_left: $section.find('[name="reason_left"]').eq(index).val(),
                            fmscr: $section.find('.fmscr:checked').eq(index).val(),
                            drug_testing: $section.find('.drug_testing:checked').eq(index).val()
                        });
                    });
                    break;

                case 'drivingExperience':
                    obj['drivingExperience'] = {
                        tt_from_date: $section.find('[name="tt-from-date"]').eq(0).val(),
                        tt_to_date: $section.find('[name="tt-to-date"]').eq(0).val(),
                        tt_miles: $section.find('[name="tt-miles"]').eq(0).val(),
                        st_from_date: $section.find('[name="st-from-date"]').eq(0).val(),
                        st_to_date: $section.find('[name="st-to-date"]').eq(0).val(),
                        st_miles: $section.find('[name="st-miles"]').eq(0).val(),
                        accident_records: [],
                        traffic_citations: [],
                        license_records: [],
                        qa: $section.find('[name="qa"]:checked').eq(0).val(),
                        qa_explain: $section.find('[name="qa_explain"]').eq(0).val(),
                        qb: $section.find('[name="qb"]:checked').eq(0).val(),
                        qb_explain: $section.find('[name="qb_explain"]').eq(0).val(),
                        qc: $section.find('[name="qc"]:checked').eq(0).val(),
                        qc_explain: $section.find('[name="qc_explain"]').prop('checked') ? 1 : -1,
                        qd: $section.find('[name="qd"]:checked').eq(0).val()
                    };

                    $section.find('[name="accident-date"]').each(function(index, element) {
                        obj['accident_records'].push({
                            date: $section.find('[name="accident-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                            nature: $section.find('[name="nature"]').eq(index).val(),
                            location: $section.find('[name="location"]').eq(index).val(),
                            fatalities: $section.find('[name="fatalities"]').eq(index).val(),
                            injuries: $section.find('[name="injuries"]').eq(index).val()
                        });
                    });

                    $section.find('[name="citation-location"]').each(function(index, element) {
                        obj['traffic_citations'].push({
                            location: $section.find('[name="citation-location"]').eq(index).val(),
                            date: $section.find('[name="citation-date"]').eq(index).val(),
                            charge: $section.find('[name="charge"]').eq(index).val(),
                            penalty: $section.find('[name="penalty"]').eq(index).val()
                        });
                    });

                    $section.find('[name="license_state"]').each(function(index, element) {
                        obj['license_records'].push({
                            state: $section.find('[name="license_state"]').eq(index).val(),
                            license_no: $section.find('[name="license_no"]').eq(index).val(),
                            type: $section.find('[name="license_type"]').eq(index).val(),
                            endorsements: $section.find('[name="endorsements"]').eq(index).val(),
                            date: $section.find('[name="license_date"]').eq(index).val()
                        });
                    });

                    break;

                default:
                    // = if (( !== 'addressRecords') && (sections[i] !== 'employmentHistory') && (sections[i] !== 'drivingExperience')) {
                    obj[sectionId][element.name] = element.value;
                    break;
            }

            application_info[sectionId] = obj;

        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '../assets/server/application_process.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: application_info,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $('body').spin(false);
                if (!data.errors) {
                    $('#applicationForm').html("<h3>" + data.message + "</h3>");
                } else {
                    bootbox.alert(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('body').spin(false);
        $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain this further please?

Comment: After doing `$("#"+sections[i]).find(".form-control")` you get the collection of elements with class `form-control`. When you apply `map` to this collection you begin iterating them. Why would you need to call `each` in the line below?

Comment: I would also add that you use quite a lot `map`s in your script. Check them  too. And you better use `each` instead of `map`: `map` is supposed to return a new array; if you don't need it, use `each`.

Comment: well my question to this is, I'm using the bootstrap library, so when using checkboxes, and radio buttons, they don't have the `form-control` class. Will this be an issue, with your solution you have offered?

Comment: You can add that class to them too or you can expand your `.find(".form-control")` selector to something like `.find(".form-control,[type=checkbox],[type=radio]")`

Comment: I tried to refactor your code a bit - see updated answer. I didn't test it though, just to give a general idea of how I would structure it. But it still may run alright.